# Firebase function on custom domain without hosting

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

So I just wanted to host my Firebase Functions on my custom domain without hosting anything. I host my website somewhere else already.

Unfortunately, Firebase throws errors when trying to deploy functions with rewrites BUT without the `public` directory OR when the `public` directory is empty.

How can I do that on Firebase without a hack and hosting some redundant stuff? I just want to host the functions on a custom domain.

Comment: To use a custom domain with your Cloud Functions, you will need to associate that domain through Firebase Hosting. If you're having trouble setting that up, please provide the steps what you tried, and the errors/problems you got.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have it associated to my Firebase Hosting. Please read my question again :) The problem is that Firebase doesn't let me deploy my functions if I'm not hosting anything but the functions.

Comment: Hey @FrankvanPuffelen could you address the issue after my explanation? :)

Comment: Sorry, I never encountered that problem. I also don't fully understand how you can host your website elsewhere, given that a single domain resolves to a single IP/hosting provider.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm using Firebase and its Functions feature to create an API for my website and I want it to be available via `api.example.com` domain. Something similar to AWS Lambda + API Gateway. Unfortunately Firebase does not give me such cool things as other hosting providers so i host the website elsewhere and just keep the API on Firebase. Unforunately it's not suited for this kind of usage - this is where my question came from.

Comment: If you host all of `api.example.com` on Firebase, that will work fine (and you can host your main example.com elsewhere). That also means that you can put a dummy `index.html` into the public directory, which will then show up on `api.example.com/index.html`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That's exactly what I finally did :) But it still feels like a hack. Amazon's AWS Lambda + API Gateway setup is something what I'd like to see in Firebase. Something like Hosting (with domain attaching etc.), but for APIs. Are you maybe planning to do something like this? Btw. Thank you very much for your time and answers! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Firebase Hosting requires at least one html page, even if your only hosting functions. Just add a blank `index.html` to a directory and point hosting to that.

Comment: Yeah, I already got to this point. Still a good answer tho :)